# Jboss 6.4EAP ClassNotFoundException from [Module "org.jboss.as.jmx:main" from local module loader @44f218 (finder: local module finder

Tags: java, jboss, ear, documentum

I am migrating an EAR file from JBoss 5 to Jboss EAP 6.4.
I added a custom module com.documentum.dfc containing all classes required by my EAR.
Strangely enough I clearly see some of the classes being loaded (com.documentum...) but still it is unable to find a Factory class that is provide in the same jar file as the classes that succesfully instantiated..
I guess it hass something to do with the Factory mechanism being loaded via another classloader, or the classloader looking in the wrong place for this specific class.. It should be searching for it in the com.documentum.dfc module, but it seems to search in org.jboss.as.jmx:main

Any idea what is going wrong here?

```
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfDocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found
    at com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfDocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DfDocumentBuilderFactory.java:27)
    at com.documentum.xml.common.DfParserFactory.<init>(DfParserFactory.java:40)
    at com.documentum.xml.common.DfParserFactory.getInstance(DfParserFactory.java:62)
    at com.documentum.fc.internal.xml.XMLUtilsFactory.getParserFactory(XMLUtilsFactory.java:17)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.CacheManifest.initCacheContentFile(CacheManifest.java:534)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.CacheManifest.init(CacheManifest.java:45)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.DefaultLocalAccessor.init(DefaultLocalAccessor.java:23)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.initDocbase(ClassCacheManager.java:597)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.initialDiscovery(ClassCacheManager.java:588)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.<init>(ClassCacheManager.java:440)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.getInstance(ClassCacheManager.java:52)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:317)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.getInstance(ModuleManager.java:43)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.<init>(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:44)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:195)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:772)
    at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)
    at nl.enexis.service.mbean.dctm.DctmSessionManager.init(DctmSessionManager.java:43)
    at nl.enexis.service.mbean.dctm.DctmSessionManager.<init>(DctmSessionManager.java:34)
    at nl.enexis.service.mbean.dctm.DctmConnectionService.getSessionManager(DctmConnectionService.java:33)
    at nl.enexis.service.mbean.dctm.DctmConnectionService.startService(DctmConnectionService.java:58)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:258)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.start(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:165)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:236)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.create(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:161)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.postRegister(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:377)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.postRegister(MBeanSupport.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.postRegister(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1024) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfDocumentBuilderFactoryImpl from [Module "org.jboss.as.jmx:main" from local module loader @44f218 (finder: local module finder @724357 (roots: d:\Programs\JBossEAP-6.4.0\modules,d:\Programs\JBossEAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\.overlays\layer-base-jboss-eap-6.4.14.CP,d:\Programs\JBossEAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:211) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.8.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfFactoryFinder.newInstance(DfFactoryFinder.java:135)
    at com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfFactoryFinder.find(DfFactoryFinder.java:273)
    at com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfDocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DfDocumentBuilderFactory.java:19)
    ... 40 more
```

Structure of my EAR:

```
-lib
-- several libs
-META-INF
--application.xml
--beans.xml
--jboss-classloading.xml
--jboss-deployment-structure.xml
-enexisServiceCommonsEJB-1.0.0.jar
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <!--
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    -->
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.documentum.dfc" export="true"/>
            <!--
            <module name="org.jboss.as.ejb3" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.system-jmx" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx" export="true"/>
            -->
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="enexisServiceCommonsEJB-1.0.0.jar">

    <dependencies>
            <module name="com.documentum.dfc" export="true"/>
<!--
            <module name="org.jboss.as.ejb3" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.system-jmx" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx" export="true"/>
-->
     </dependencies>
    <local-last value="true" />
  </sub-deployment>  

</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Tibco EMS queues/topic in Jboss we need to configure and deploy Generic JMS resource adapter in jboss. Follow the steps below to configure JMS resource adapter in JBOSS7 or Jboss eap 6.4:

- Step1: Create the following folders structure in jboss installation dir \modules\com\tibco\tibjms\main
  Copy tibjms.jar and tibcrypt.jar  to \modules\com\tibco\tibjms\main and 
  Create module.xml  with the following content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.tibco.jms">
      <resources> 
          <resource-root path="tibcrypt.jar"/>
          <resource-root path="tibjms.jar"/>
          <!-- Insert resources here -->
      </resources>
      <dependencies>
          <!-- Insert dependencies here -->
          <module name="javax.api"/>
          <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
      </dependencies>    
  </module>
  ```
- Step 2: Open \jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\jts\main\module.xml and \jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\ee\main\module.xml add following dependency in both the locations

  ```
  <dependencies>      
      <module name="com.tibco.tibjms"/> 
  </dependencies>
  ```
- Step3: Open standalone_XXX.xml (Which ever file u r using) (\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml) and add the following lines in

  ```
  <mdb>
      <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="genericra.rar"/>   
      <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/> 
  </mdb>
  ```
- Step4: Restart the server and see the exception got resolved or not. With the above steps my problem resolved. All the best.